# Why task is not running even when execution is inside the task method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await, task-parallel-library

So this is WPF + MVVM + .NET 4.8 + WCT.

I have an `AsyncRelayCommand` in my VM class defined like this:

```
private AsyncRelayCommand _StartSyncCommand;
public AsyncRelayCommand StartSyncCommand
{
  get
  {
    _StartSyncCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(Pump, () => !_StartSyncCommand.IsRunning);
    return _StartSyncCommand;
  }
}
```

The actual task method contains an async iterator and looks like this:

```
private async Task Pump(CancellationToken token)
{
  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));

  try
  {
    await foreach (var item in applicationService.FetchItems())
    {
      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      ...
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ee)
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

This method raises property change notification on `IsBusy` property (to show wait cursor in the UI). However when I check the status of `StartSyncCommand` in the property, it tells me that it is not running.

```
public bool IsBusy => StartSyncCommand.IsRunning;
```

I can't see why this should be the case. The method is actually running when the property change notification occurs. I can see the method in the call stack.

What am I missing here?

### Update

This is getting weirder. `StartSyncCommand.ExecutionTask` itself is `null` while I'm inside the task method:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All asynchronous methods begin executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), as I explain on my blog. So it's not surprising to me that at the beginning of your `async` method that its task is null (and thus presumably the busy property is false). I haven't looked at the WCT code, but I expect under the hood it looks something like this:

```
ExecutionTask = execute();
IsRunning = true;
```

(where `execute` is a delegate pointing to your `Pump` method)

Since `Pump` hasn't hit its first `await` yet, it hasn't returned a task yet, so `ExecutionTask` hasn't been set.

You *can* work around this by doing an `await Task.Yield();` at the beginning of `Pump`, but IMO a cleaner solution would be to move the `OnPropertyChanged` call outside `Pump`, or remove it entirely and just forward the property change notifications from `IsRunning`.

Comment: Thanks. This essentially was the problem. However, I do not have control over `IsRunning`, as it is part of `AsyncRelayCommand` and lives inside WCT. What I had to do instead was to call `Pump()` from inside a `Task.Run()` call. Not sure if that defeats the purpose of async/await, but at least now it behaves correctly. I'll accept this as answer since it identifies the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problem, here is what I ended up with:

```
private AsyncRelayCommand _StartSyncCommand;
public AsyncRelayCommand StartSyncCommand
{
  get
  {
    _StartSyncCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(token =>
    {
      return Task.Run(async () =>
      {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
        await Pump(token);
      });
    }, 
    () => !_StartSyncCommand.IsRunning);
    return _StartSyncCommand;
  }
}
```

As @Stephen correctly pointed out in his answer, `AsyncRelayCommand` does not create an run the task it created from the supplied async method till it hits the first `await` in the method, which means that trying to check `IsRunning` or `ExecutionTask` on the command object will not return desired results before that `await` line is reached. With a `Task.Run()` call, I'm force-creating and running the task before issuing my property change notifications.